# Handle an aray of inputs in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, onchange

Im trying to handle an aray of inputs in react which are viewed by ".map" function.
The problem is I couldn't give the field a specific value. As a result i couldn't handle the input in onChange function.

I have list of card each card will have a Admin description input and two buttons each one will send a different request.

Here A made the function that present the cards. The porplem is with the  input

```
function createrequestcard(prop){
    return(
    <Card className="text-center" key={prop._id}>
     <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="requestspart1" class="left">
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Admin Description</Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                <textarea 
                // --> Value of the index in aray
                // --> Handle Change of input
                />
                </Card.Text>
             </Card.Body>
  </div>
  <div id="requestspart3" class="left">
        <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>CREATE</Card.Title>
        <Button variant="outline-success" className="AdminRequestButton">APPROVE</Button>   
        <Button variant="outline-danger" className="AdminRequestButton">DENY</Button>
      </Card.Body>
    </div>
    </div>
</Card>
)
}
```

In initialising values on class

```
    this.state = {
        requests: [],
        description: '', 
    }
}
```

The request aray is updated from the backend:

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.checkloginstatus();

    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/request', {withCredentials: true})
    .then(resp => {
      this.setState({requests: resp.data})
    }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

And in render function:

```
<div>
{this.state.requests.map(createrequestcard)}
</div>
```

Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: Either change your `createrequestcard` into a `RequestCard` Component. Then you can easily handle state in the component or pass a function that can change your `state.requests` value to the `createrequestcard` function.

Comment: you wan to change request object which is passed to card?right,can you specify what member should be modified when user changed textbox value of card?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass index in `map` method like the below,

```
<div>
{this.state.requests.map((req,index) => createrequestcard(req, inex))}
</div>

function createrequestcard(prop, index){
```

The structure of `map` method is like below

```
map((element) => { ... } )
map((element, index) => { ... } )
map((element, index, array) => { ... } )
```

Answer (score 0):

your card component should defined as follow, here i have named it RequestCard (just to make more readable),
this component will get handleOnChange as argument , we will pass updated value to it,when onchange event occurs in
textarea.

```
function RequestCard(props){
return(
<Card className="text-center" key={prop._id}>
 <div class="wrapper">
<div id={props.id} class="left">
        <Card.Body>
          <Card.Title>Admin Description</Card.Title>
            <Card.Text>
            <textarea  
             onChange={(e)=>props.handleOnChange(e.target.value)}
            // --> Value of the index in aray
            // --> Handle Change of input
            />
            </Card.Text>
         </Card.Body>
 </div>
 <div id="requestspart3" class="left">
    <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>CREATE</Card.Title>
    <Button variant="outline-success" className="AdminRequestButton">APPROVE</Button>   
    <Button variant="outline-danger" className="AdminRequestButton">DENY</Button>
  </Card.Body>
</div>
</div>
</Card>
 )}
```

now you should render it as follow

```
<div>
  {this.state.requests.map((request,index)=>{
  return <RequestCard id={index} handleOnChange={(updatedValue)=>this.handleOnChange(index,updatedValue)}
})}
```

finally your handleOnChange of parent component should be like this,

```
handleOnChange=(index,updatedValue)=>{
let curState=this.state;
curState.requests[index].value=updatedValue;//note that i am not aware what member of request you want to update
//so i assume value is the member of request object,you can change whatever you want
this.setState(curState);
}
```